# It looks like opencv swaps the blue and red channels?

Tags: opencv

[image]

I am new to opencv.
I found the following code swaps red and blue channel when I fed sRGB png to it. Which function should I blame, imread or fromarray?

Comment: `OpenCV` is in `BGR` mode, while `Image` or `Matplotlib` is in `RGB` mode.

Comment: @Kinght金 ok, but why they have different mode ? it makes everything's more complicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, OpenCV follows BGR color convention internally. However, you may either use [`cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) before displaying your image using a **third party function**(`display()` in this case). Or you can also use `cv2.imshow()` method to debug images, which doesn't require `cv2.cvtColor()`

Answer (score 4):

Rather simple option would be swapping the R and B channels:

```
img = img[:, :, ::-1]
```

Comment: I am quite sure that this answer isn't appreciated enough and it should be.